# Chrome low memory error when javascript tries to send file to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I made a web app that takes file from form and send it to the server using ajax then updating the page. It works perfectly fine in browsers except chrome mobile. I have tried it in android. which shows `unable to complete previous operation due to low memory` and iOS which returns an error.

I want to fix this problem for users who will use this web app. so solutions like clearing up cache -which didn't work btw- and such aren't really sufficient.

here is my javascript code if it helps:

```
file = document.getElementById('file');

fd = new FormData();
fd.append( 'file', file.files && file.files.length > 0? file.files[0] : null);

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: fd,
    success: function (data, status, request) {
        // update UI here
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error has occurred");
    }
});
```

I just wanted to add that the website works just fine in chrome-mobile as long as I don't select any files. Also I have tested it in safari and it works

**EDIT**: reasons why I believe this is a problem related to chrome and NOT device memory

- It works on safari and firefox in THE SAME DEVICE
- It didn't work in chrome even after clearing up cache
- the device has a lot of free space and memory. and has been cleaned before running the app on chrome
- the file in questions is LITERALLY 1.57KB. I'm sorry but I don't see how uploading a 1KB file could cause low memory

## what is the questions in a nutshell:

is there a workaround for javascript in chrome? just as an example flask doesn't work well in IE8 and earlier, so using inline-block can correct the question somehow. Is it possible that `FormData()` for example doesn't work correctly on chrome? if yes what are the alternatives? that is why I asked the question and that was the way I looked at the problem if it helps

Comment: So...... what's the question?  Other than "I want it to fix it."?  You can't really control the amount of free memory on someones device.

Comment: yes I want to fix it because it has nothing to do with free memory as far as I can tell. the device I tested it on has a lot of free storage and memory and I cleared the chache too but still didn't work in chrome. but it worked in firefox and safair so I guess there must be something that could be done. Like how in css some styling doesn't work in some browsers. I thought the problem is like this

Comment: I would suggest making a version of your submit that does not use javascript at all.  Make a normal form submit with a file selection to upload the file.  If the issue persists, then this is *not* a javascript issue.  Given that all your script is doing is making an ajax request to submit the file, which is essentially mimicing a normal form submit, but with ajax, the issue will persist with a normal form submit.

Comment: It was actually a normal website with no java script. but the task at server is VERY heavy so I used celery. java script is absolutely necessary to pull the progress from the server. It worked just fine before adding the file. then once I added the file upload all hell broke loose in chrome -it worked before-. The weird thing is before I actually read the file on js then uploaded the text to server. I think it has something to do with the new added FormData() but I found no post about it not working in chrome

Comment: I'm not suggesting you leave it as a non ajax submit.  I'm suggesting you try the normal form submit as a debugging tool to rule out javascript as part of the issue.

Comment: will try! Thank for your help :D